# .slideDown() Doesn't Seem To Work

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery's [**.slideUp()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) doesn't work after [**.append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is used to append value of textarea to the div. 
**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="cont">
            <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
            <button onclick="click()">Click</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function click(){
    var txt = $('#txt').val();
    var html = document.createElement('div');
    $(html).hide().html(txt);
    $('#cont').append(html);
    $(html).slideUp(500);
}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is because when I used **.show()** instead of **.slideUp()** it works fine.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but if you're going to use jQuery at all why not use it to simplify creation of your element(s) too: `$("<div/>").hide().html(txt).appendTo('#cont').slideDown(500);`

Comment: @nnnnn The reason I didn't do this is because in my actual scenario I use _.before()_ instead of _append()_. Does that make sense?

Comment: @nnnnn nevermind that was a stupid comment b/c _.insertBefore()_. Thanks a ton you were very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well...slideDown let the element be shown and slideUp let it be hidden. try

```
    $(html).slideDown(500)
```

---

### @ Philip Hardyhis saying: fixes my problem. However, is there a way to have it slide up from the bottom without having to use .animate()

i don't think so, but I think it would be pretty easy:
just put a div-element inside of the html (with $(html) it will be hard to handle) lets call it "myDiv" and put every content of the html in myDiv

then move the div outside of the window and do the animation (note to move it outside at the bottom you need to temporary disable scrolls of window)

```
$(document).css('overflow','hidden');
$("#myDiv").css({'top':$(document).height(), 'opacity':'0'});
/*outside of the window and transparent*/
$("#myDiv").animate({
    'opacity':'1',
    'top':'0'
},2000, function(){$(document).css('overflow','auto');});
```

i think it should work like this

Comment: This fixes my problem. However, is there a way to have it slide up from the bottom without having to use _.animate()_

Comment: Sorry for bringing a new problem to the table after I said it was answered and causing confusion. I am very new to the forum. This works great. Thank you so much!

Comment: :) i'm happy that i could help you

Answer (score 1):

Hide the new div prior to adding it to `#cont` - then call `.slideDown` on it to reveal:

```
// When the button is pressed
$("button").on("click", function(){
    // Create a new DIV with our text as its content
    $("<div>", { text: $("#txt").val() } )
         // Make it invisible, append it, and then slide it into view
        .hide().appendTo("#cont").slideDown(500); 
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Zp5w/1/

Answer (score 1):

Aside, from L. Monty already pointed out you can condense your function quite a bit by making use of jQuery's chaining.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('<div>')
       .html($('#txt').val())
       .appendTo('#cont')
       .slideDown(0).slideUp('slow');
});​
```

Comment: I've always wondered what people were doing when they did that haha. Thank you so much!

Comment: you also did the the mistake of using slideUp instead of slideDown ;)